# enable wireless on an HP Pavillion dv4

Tags: wireless

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 on an HP Pavillion DV4 and I cannot get the Wireless antenna turned on.  I think I have the right drivers downloaded, but when I go into Network > Wireless I cannot switch it to "on"... it's grey'd out.  The laptop has a soft switch for the antenna on the top of the keyboard, but that does not appear to work

Comment: Can you detail which drivers you've downloaded and from where. Can you also post the wireless card model.

Answer (score 1):

Try this link:

https://nfolamp.wordpress.com/2011/10/15/ubuntu-11-10-getting-wireless-bcm4311-working/

Worked on my Dell D430.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.